# Excel Index Matching a name based upon the highest value

Tags: indexing, excel-formula

I'm trying to make an excel formula to search through an array for multiple criteria. The array is a list of names that have been nominated for a certain costume next to the amount of the bid. I need to go through an identify the highest bid per costume type and then have it read that name out.

The Victim is in E:E, the costume in D:D, and the bid in F:F.

I can get the highest bid amount based on the costume with
=SUMIFS(F:F,E:E,D:D)

And I can get the highest bidder overall with 
=INDEX(D:D, MATCH(MAX(BID), BID, 0))

The problem is I do not know how to combine the formulas to get the highest bidder based on the costume names (located at I14:I19). If this is too vague I can try and upload a picture to help make it clear.

Comment: `=INDEX(D:D,MATCH(F:F,MAX(IF(E:E = I14,F:F)),0))` Paste into j14.  This is an Array formula and must be qualified by ctrl-shift-enter.  Then copy down.

Comment: `=INDEX(D:D,MATCH(MAX(IF(E:E = I14,F:F)),F:F,0))` sorry had something backwards.

Comment: You sir, are my hero. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
=INDEX(D:D,MATCH(MAX(IF(E:E = I14,F:F)),F:F,0))
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter

`MAX(IF(E:E = I14,F:F))` returns the MAX value in Column F where Costume Type in column E equals the Costume Type in Cell I14.

`MATCH(MAX(IF(E:E = I14,F:F)),F:F,0)` then finds the value returned by the max statement in column F and returns the row number.

Then it is easy to find the value in Column D where the row equals the above with INDEX.

Now one thing, this is a shortcut that assumes that the bid values in column F are unique.  Because the MATCH function stops at finding the first correct answer, if there are duplicates in Column F it will find the first row that matches regardless of costume type.

To prevent this another if statement in the MATCH function will help.

```
=INDEX(D:D,MATCH(MAX(IF(E:E = I14,F:F)),IF(E:E = I14,F:F),0))
```

This then filters the range being searched by the MATCH function to those only that have matching costume types to the desired search.